# Square grid tessellation for arbitrary polygon in Python

Tags: python, tessellation

So as the question suggests, I need to approximate an arbitrary polygon into equal-sized squares. What's the best way to do this? I've looked at something like Tesspy, but it uses geographical data (mercantile, I assume) to create the bounding boxes. The output looks exactly like what I need, that is covering an area with square grids, but for without any sort of geographic information. How do I do that?

Image from Tesspy for reference is attached below.

Any help will be great. Thanks!

[image]